# Configuring email (PHP Mail) with Craft

Tags: emails

I'm trying to set up a basic PHP Mail setup with Craft. I really just need it set up to handle new account activation e-mails. I can't seem to find any instructions on the Craft site or elsewhere on how to set this up specifically for Craft. Does Craft require any specific configuration for PHP Mail to work?

Thanks.

Comment: PHP Mail is notoriously unreliable... I'd highly recommend using an SMTP service, like [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) or [SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Craft require any specific configuration for PHP Mail to work?

No.  Craft assumes that [PHP's mail](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php) function is already working if that's what you've selected under Settings->Email in the control panel.

You don't mention what the actual problem you're having is (i.e. getting an error message or email not being delivered, etc.), but there is a support article here that can help you debug both of those issues: https://craftcms.com/support/troubleshooting-email-errors